# FFMPEG: Set output res and bitrate depending upon input video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm processing user videos with differing aspect ratios. It seems FFMPEG only allows you to specify a fixed resolution. I want the output res to be appropriate for the input res. Similarly, I'd like FFMPEG to intelligently set the output bitrate based on the input video: obviously it shouldn't be any bigger than the input.

I can get the properties of a video with,

```
ffmpeg -i example.flv
```

But this requires some ugly parsing of the output, so I'm wondering if FFMPEG or some other tool has a more direct facility.

Basically, I have the Youtube problem: crap comes in, reasonably uniform quality should come out.

Comment: Are you looking for a script that outputs the properties in an easily parsable format?

Comment: That would be a good start. I don't trust my own parsing because the output might change in unexpected edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question, but I'd like to add my 2 cents for what its worth.

Firstly, using `ffmpeg` to get info on the video does give ugly output. Try using `ffprobe` (bundled with `ffmpeg`) instead. You can add options like `-print_format json -pretty` to get nice JSON output of the information, which is much easier to parse.

Additionally, have a look at the following article: http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/
Its also a bit dated but should help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Someone named ahaslam may have already written a [short bash script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=965329) that addresses your problem.

Comment: I believe the script is something else. It computes the bitrate to fit some file size.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` has an library interface - I know nothing about it, but maybe you could use that to get the information directly into your code?

http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html

Answer (score 1):

Using a script seems like the right answer to the question I asked, but I should have mentioned that I'm using PandaStream. I was concerned because PandaStream has you specify a fixed output res, but apparently it has logic such that the input video gets bounded to this resolution, e.g. for the output res 480x270, a 4:3 video will be encoded at 360x270.

This seems like a good compromise. Just set Panda to output a 16:9 res and then 16:10 and 4:3 vids will come out fine for most purposes.

Comment: You could have added this info as "half" a comment on DaveParillo's answer and "half" an edit thus fixing your question. Unless this actually is answering your question (since I don't quite follow you here), to which I'd still advise doing the two previous action, and keeping this answer, fixing it according to the new question, and accepting it.